# reading CSV file into hashmap

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, frequency

I have a CSV file which contain fields as follows:
Field 1, Field 2,Field 3, the frequency , and I want to assign it to hash map variable in Java. the code below from [here](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) is to scan the file and calculate the frequency for each line, However I have the file with frequencies already so I just need to read a few lines. so I replace

```
    // split the transaction into items
```

with

```
        String[] lineSplited = line.split(" "); 
        String itemString = lineSplited[0];
        Integer count = Integer.valueOf(lineSplited[1]);
        mapSupport.put(itemString, count);
```

in the original code

```
private void DetermineFrequencyOfSingleItems(String input,
            final Map<String, Integer> mapSupport)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //Create object for reading the input file
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
        String line;
        // for each line (transaction) until the end of file
        while( ((line = reader.readLine())!= null)){ 
            // if the line is  a comment, is  empty or is a
            // kind of metadata
            if (line.isEmpty() == true ||
                    line.charAt(0) == '#' || line.charAt(0) == '%'
                            || line.charAt(0) == '@') {
                continue;
            }

            // split the transaction into items
            String[] lineSplited = line.split(" ");
             // for each item in the transaction
            for(String itemString : lineSplited){ 
                // increase the support count of the item
                Integer count = mapSupport.get(itemString);
                if(count == null){
                    mapSupport.put(itemString, 1);
                }else{
                    mapSupport.put(itemString, ++count);
                }
            }
            // increase the transaction count
            transactionCount++;
        }
        // close the input file
        reader.close();
    }
```

but it does not work, any suggestion?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What kind of debugging have you done? Do you have sample CSV data?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AlgoFPGrowth_Strings.DetermineFrequencyOfSingleItems(AlgoFPGrowth_Strings.java:205)

Comment: And which line (in your code sample) is line 205?

Comment: .java:2‌​05 : String[] lineSplited = line.split(" ");

Comment: Are you sure? You check for null in the while statement, and you would have gotten a nullP in the if statement directly above, so it doesn't make sense. **The code works** for me when I tested locally.

Comment: the original code works perfectly, but after the modification it gives me the error

Comment: From where you are calling `DetermineFrequencyOfSingleItems` method? Are you passing second argument `null` there? I don't see any other area in this method where you can get `NullPointerException`

Comment: I did not change anything in the call , just pass the file,  final Map<String, Integer> mapSupport = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  DetermineFrequencyOfSingleItems( "freqCount.csv", mapSupport);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original program, the line frequency is counted so the CSV lines are split using " "(space) makes no difference.

But since you are reading the data, you have to split using "," (comma) and trim the String before using as key in your map or parsing as Integer.

And please be specific about your problem and what kind of error you get.

Since your file is tab spaced and you want the last field as count and rest as the key value, try

```
String frequency = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf('\t')+1);// Parse as Integer 
String key=line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf('\t'));
mapSupport.put(key,Integer.parseInt(frequency));
```

Comment: thanks, but I did not get why I have to trim the string?  I have csv file with four fields and I want to store the three fields as key and the fourth as value , how can I do that? the original code counts the frequency but as I have it already I just want to import the file into mapSupport (the hashmap variable)

Comment: Oh then you have to split using '\t'. Try using line.split("\t");

Comment: thanks, one last question when I need the frequency can I use :     String[] lineSplited = line.split("\t ",3); to split the line into two parts , string and frequency?

Comment: the integer parameter in the split is used to specify limit. The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times. In your case if each line contains four values and last part is your frequecy, then use split("\t") and get the frequency from lineSplited[3]. (Be sure all line has four fields)

Comment: Or try this: 
                String frequency = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf('\t')+1);// Parse as Integer
  String key=line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf('\t'));
  mapSupport.put(key,Integer.parseInt(frequency));